Pyinstaller: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gradio_rangeslider'
I am trying to package my python program using 'gradio' for the GUI and the custom gradio addon 'gradio_rangeslider' (by freddyaboulton on GitHub).
Previously I was unable to import gradio until I followed this thread (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/8108). I added --collect-data=gradio and --collect-data=gradio_client to the command line argument and specified in the .spec file to import gradio as 'py' files.
i generated a .spec file by using: pyi-makespec --additional-hooks-dir="build_deps\\" --collect-data=gradio_client --collect-data=gradio --hidden-import pyarrow.vendored.version --onefile Program_name.py
The .spec file is as follows
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = []
datas += collect_data_files('gradio_client')
datas += collect_data_files('gradio')


a = Analysis(
    ['Program_name.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=['pyarrow.vendored.version'],
    hookspath=['build_deps\\'],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
    module_collection_mode={
        'gradio': 'py',
    },
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Program_name',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)

I then ran: pyinstaller --clean --noconfirm Program_name.spec
The .exe was constructed but when I run it i get the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Program_name.py", line 22, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gradio_rangeslider'
[PYI-24644:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'Program_name' due to unhandled exception!

I have trieed adding --collect-data=gradio_rangeslider to the pyi-makespec command and setting gradio_rangeslider as 'py' compile mode in the .spec file.
module_collection_mode={
        'gradio': 'py',
        'gradio_rangeslider ': 'py'
    },

But I still get the same error. I am unsure if this module is configured correctly, or if I am missing something. All modules are installed in a python virtual environment and pyinstaller is being run from within the virtual environment. The code runs file as a python file.
Any help with this would be appreciated.
EDIT: found this message in the pyinstaller CMD outputs WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'gradio_rangeslider' as it is not a package.
I don't know why it thinks its not a package.
